# How do I create named popup windows?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, the `window.open` function takes as a second argument the name of a window. I am trying to open Google in a new named window with

```
window.open('http://google.com/', 'myGoogleWindow');​
```

but nothing happens. However,

```
window.open('http://google.com/');
```

works. However, I want to name the window since I would like to programmatically close it later. How do I open a popup in a named window?

Comment: works without any issue here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K3bQk/

Comment: Yes, it works for me also in JSFiddle.

Comment: If you want to close it later put it into a variable that you will have access too then call the close() method on that variable object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the window name is unnecessary if all you want to do is close the window later on. The window name exists so that you can reuse the window if it was already opened, and so that links with a matching `target` attribute will load in your window.

Referring to [Mozilla's window.open() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open), the window.open() function returns a window object reference. Using that reference, you can close the window when you're done with it:

```
var myWindow = window.open('http://example.org/');
// Later...
myWindow.close();
```